How Might I Add an External Link to the Sitecore Documentation Page?
Sitecore 9.3 (soon to upgrade to 10.3):
We'd like to add a link to an external page to the Documentation page in our CMS (sitecore/shell/sitecore/client/Applications/ExternalApplication?id=[GUID info deleted]).  This is, for clarity, the page which opens upon clicking the Documentation button in LaunchPad.  
Efforts so far, e.g., adding a page with a link field to the Documentation folder, haven't worked. Clicking the link to this on the documentation page errors out, with no useful information in the Sitecore or IIS logs.
We believe we could accomplish this by putting the link in a PDF document and putting the PDF in the Documentation folder, but would like to avoid that extra redirection step if possible.  Can this be done?

Is this "Sitecore Documentation Page" a page hosted in your own Sitecore environment? Perhaps you can provide some screenshots as to where you want the link to appear.

Could you please share the error page screenshot as well? And whatever you get in the logs.

That button is custom to your implementation. You will need to contact your implementation partner to understand how it was implemented. That is not an out of the box button.

Ah, I hadn't realized this was custom; it's been around for a while.  Once I realized that I was able to track it down and make appropriate changes.  Thanks!
